# Python error when generating tf.record file - Tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu, anaconda

I am using TensorFlow 2.5.0 (python 3.9, Ubuntu 20.04, and Anaconda 3) to create a custom object detector. I have labeled my images and have followed [this](https://medium.com/swlh/creating-your-own-custom-object-detector-using-transfer-learning-f26918697889) tutorial to get to this point. However, I am getting the following error (**see last line of error listed below**) when trying to create my tf.record files:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/database/Custom-Object-Detector-Workspace/Project/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 169, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/database/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/home/database/python3.9/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 303, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/database/python3.9/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 251, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/database/Custom-Object-Detector-Workspace/Project/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 159, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "/home/database/tensorflow/Custom-Object-Detector-Workspace/Project/scripts/generate_tfrecord.py", line 113, in create_tf_example
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
  File "/home/database/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 117, in read
    self._preread_check()
  File "/home/database/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/lib/io/file_io.py", line 79, in _preread_check
    self._read_buf = _pywrap_file_io.BufferedInputStream(
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/database/images/test/DJI_0001_008.jpg; No such file or directory
```

I do not have a file in the image folder named DJI_0001_008.jpg. To make sure photos were named uniquely, I appended unique letters to each file name (between the _008 and the .jpg extension) so that when combined they could each be distinguished as separate files. A quick `locate` command brings up all files in my training and testing folders with the filename in it:

```
/images/test/DJI_0001_008_r.jpg
/images/test/DJI_0001_008_r.xml
/images/train/DJI_0001_008_b.jpg
/images/train/DJI_0001_008_b.xml
/images/train/DJI_0001_008_m.jpg
/images/train/DJI_0001_008_m.xml
```

As you can see, each DJI_0001_008.jpg has a unique letter appended after it to both the photo itself and before the file extension. But the generate_tfrecord.py script is still throwing this error.

**How can I fix this error?** Is this a naming error? If so, would it be better to rename them so that the "DJI_0001_008" is not in any of the filenames? I have discovered that some of the images have .jpg extensions and others have .JPG extensions, would that be a factor here?

```
#######################################################
```

The error is generated by running these anaconda commands

```
#Activate Anaconda environment
conda activate tensorflow

#Set workplace directory where the python script is in
cd /home/desired_directory

#run generate_tfrecord.py script, set for creating a tf.record file in the test folder:
python3 generate_tfrecord.py -x /home/tensorflow_ihb/Custom-Object-Detector-Workspace/Project/images/test -l /home/tensorflow_ihb/Custom-Object-Detector-Workspace/Project/annotations/label_map.pbtxt -o /home/tensorflow_ihb/Custom-Object-Detector-Workspace/Project/annotations/test.record -c /home/tensorflow_ihb/Custom-Object-Detector-Workspace/Project/annotations/test.csv
```

Here is the generate_tfrecord.py script that generates the error:

```
""" Sample TensorFlow XML-to-TFRecord converter

usage: generate_tfrecord.py [-h] [-x XML_DIR] [-l LABELS_PATH] [-o OUTPUT_PATH] [-i IMAGE_DIR] [-c CSV_PATH]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -x XML_DIR, --xml_dir XML_DIR
                        Path to the folder where the input .xml files are stored.
  -l LABELS_PATH, --labels_path LABELS_PATH
                        Path to the labels (.pbtxt) file.
  -o OUTPUT_PATH, --output_path OUTPUT_PATH
                        Path of output TFRecord (.record) file.
  -i IMAGE_DIR, --image_dir IMAGE_DIR
                        Path to the folder where the input image files are stored. Defaults to the same directory as XML_DIR.
  -c CSV_PATH, --csv_path CSV_PATH
                        Path of output .csv file. If none provided, then no file will be written.
"""

import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import io
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import argparse

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'    # Suppress TensorFlow logging (1)
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
from PIL import Image
from object_detection.utils import dataset_util, label_map_util
from collections import namedtuple

# Initiate argument parser
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="Sample TensorFlow XML-to-TFRecord converter")
parser.add_argument("-x",
                    "--xml_dir",
                    help="Path to the folder where the input .xml files are stored.",
                    type=str)
parser.add_argument("-l",
                    "--labels_path",
                    help="Path to the labels (.pbtxt) file.", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-o",
                    "--output_path",
                    help="Path of output TFRecord (.record) file.", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-i",
                    "--image_dir",
                    help="Path to the folder where the input image files are stored. "
                         "Defaults to the same directory as XML_DIR.",
                    type=str, default=None)
parser.add_argument("-c",
                    "--csv_path",
                    help="Path of output .csv file. If none provided, then no file will be "
                         "written.",
                    type=str, default=None)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.image_dir is None:
    args.image_dir = args.xml_dir

label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(args.labels_path)
label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(label_map)


def xml_to_csv(path):
    """Iterates through all .xml files (generated by labelImg) in a given directory and combines
    them in a single Pandas dataframe.

    Parameters:
    ----------
    path : str
        The path containing the .xml files
    Returns
    -------
    Pandas DataFrame
        The produced dataframe
    """

    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                     int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(member[4][0].text),
                     int(member[4][1].text),
                     int(member[4][2].text),
                     int(member[4][3].text)
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height',
                   'class', 'xmin', 'xmax', 'ymin', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    xml_df.to_csv("dataset.csv")
    return xml_df


def class_text_to_int(row_label):
    return label_map_dict[row_label]


def split(df, group):
    data = namedtuple('data', ['filename', 'object'])
    gb = df.groupby(group)
    return [data(filename, gb.get_group(x)) for filename, x in zip(gb.groups.keys(), gb.groups)]


def create_tf_example(group, path):
    with tf.gfile.GFile(os.path.join(path, '{}'.format(group.filename)), 'rb') as fid:
        encoded_jpg = fid.read()
    encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
    image = Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
    width, height = image.size

    filename = group.filename.encode('utf8')
    image_format = b'jpg'
    xmins = []
    xmaxs = []
    ymins = []
    ymaxs = []
    classes_text = []
    classes = []

    for index, row in group.object.iterrows():
        xmins.append(row['xmin'] / width)
        xmaxs.append(row['xmax'] / width)
        ymins.append(row['ymin'] / height)
        ymaxs.append(row['ymax'] / height)
        classes_text.append(row['class'].encode('utf8'))
        classes.append(class_text_to_int(row['class']))

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
    }))
    return tf_example


def main(_):

    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(args.output_path)
    path = os.path.join(args.image_dir)
    examples = xml_to_csv(args.xml_dir)
    grouped = split(examples, 'filename')
    for group in grouped:
        tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
        writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
    writer.close()
    print('Successfully created the TFRecord file: {}'.format(args.output_path))
    if args.csv_path is not None:
        examples.to_csv(args.csv_path, index=None)
        print('Successfully created the CSV file: {}'.format(args.csv_path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Comment: Update - I have renamed each of the pairs of .jpg and .xml files, and I still get the same answer. I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I changed this and i was able to generate my tf.records test and train records from my csv's.

Please note that i did this for both the test and train CSV's

I changed:

```
python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/test_labels.csv  --output_path=data/test.record
```

to

```
python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=data/test_labels.csv  --output_path=data/test.record --image_dir=images
```

please note i ran this code from my dir:
-desktop

- object-detection

Basically in your terminal code need to add the path back to where you created the csv's from with all the image's in.

Answer (score 0):

After I renamed the files, I failed to rename the file name within the .xml file itself.

For instance, the .xml annotation to "image9.jpg" still read (after changing the name):

```
<annotation>
    <folder>resized</folder>
    <filename>DJI_0001_007.jpg</filename>
    <path>C:\image_path\resized\DJI_0001_007.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>1024</width>
        <height>1024</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>Class_name</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>1</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>1</xmin>
            <ymin>9</ymin>
            <xmax>643</xmax>
            <ymax>760</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

This seems to be the problem. It appears that it is either necessary to go back through and annotate the images again to generate new .xml files, or find a way to replace the name within the .xml file.